# Python read/write file exercise. How to print a list to a text file

Tags: python, list, enumerate

New to python. Would anyone know how to make it so the text file would have an output of this enumerated list? I currently can only see it happen if it prints to console, but can't make it print to that format in text file.

For example (I know this isn't right format but just trying to show expected output) this prints out to the console, but not to file.

```
tv_characters = ["Will Byers", "Tyrion Lannister", "Oliver Queen", "Jean Luc Picard", "Malcom Reynolds", "The Doctor", "Sam Winchester", "Sherlock Holmes"]

for index , character in enumerate(tv_characters):
  f = open("text", "w")
  print("{0}: {1}\n".format(index+1, character))
```

It's supposed to be having the print functionality when set up like this but this only has an output of the last name in list.

```
tv_characters = ["Will Byers", "Tyrion Lannister", "Oliver Queen", "Jean Luc Picard", "Malcom Reynolds", "The Doctor", "Sam Winchester", "Sherlock Holmes"]

# Write out my character list to a file called "text"
for index , character in enumerate(tv_characters):
  f = open("text", "w")
  f.write("{0}: {1}\n".format(index+1, character))
  f.close()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Open the file **before**, and close it **after** the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently opening & closing the file within the loop, which is the root cause.

Use `with` which automatically takes care of opening and closing the file and put `for` loop under it:

```
tv_characters = ['Will Byers', 'Tyrion Lannister', 'Oliver Queen', 'Jean Luc Picard', 'Malcom Reynolds', 'The Doctor', 'Sam Winchester', 'Sherlock Holmes']
with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    # Write out my character list to a file called 'text'
    for index, character in enumerate(tv_characters):
      f.write(f'{index+1}: {character}\n')
```

Comment: It’s good that you suggested OP use `with`, but what about f-strings instead of `format`?! `f.write(f’{index+1}: {character}\n’)`.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment, so I apologize. If I understand your question correctly this should help! (python3)

```
# Your char list
tv_characters = ["Will Byers", "Tyrion Lannister", "Oliver Queen", "Jean Luc Picard", "Malcom Reynolds", "The Doctor", "Sam Winchester", "Sherlock Holmes"]

# no need to open and close over and over
f = open("text", "w")

for index, character in enumerate(tv_characters) : f.write(f"{index+1}: {character}\n") # basic one liner

# will close once it's done, cleans up code
f.close()
```